# Import tensorflow in python failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tried to follow instructions for installing Tensorflow for windows (new Win 10 machine Dell Precision 7720 with Nvidia P5000), but I am running into an issue.

Installed (successfully):

- CUDA Toolkit 8.0 (samples work)
- cuDnn v5.1
- Python 3.5.2 (python works)

ran:
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

completed successfully...

Then invoked a python shell

entered:
import tensorflow as tf

on enter I get:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py"
, line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <m
odule>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49
, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py"
, line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 906, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py"
, line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_int
ernal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\e27321\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
>>>
```

Looked at common install issues, but couldn't make out which one this may have fallen into...

Any ideas on what may have gone wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Visual C++ installed on your computer? You'll need that to run tensorflow, as a lot of it is written in C++.

If you do, according to this link https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8385 you should check first if your 'CUDA_HOME' is properly set and CUDA and cuDNN DLLs directories are in your PATH. If that fails reinstall Visual C++ with the link on the page above.

Comment: I tried all the above and I still get the exact error as before.

Comment: I am now trying to use anaconda's python, I can create a session for tensorflow (installing tensorflow without gpu support) and it seems to work fine, but when i create a new anaconda session and install tensorflow-gpu, I still get the above error on import. I have also compiled the cuda sample deviceQuery, and it finds my GPU fine.